# Simple Java Generics Example

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to learn generics.  I thought I'd start with a simple example that illustrates my current understanding of the subject, but that isn't working and I don't know why.  The error I recieve is like many others who have tried working with generics: "The method ... in the type ... is not applicable for the arguments ..."

I've read through [Lesson: Generics (The Java Tutorials > Bonus)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) and many exchange posts, so I'm clearly misunderstanding a key concept that is NOT being answered by the multitude of duplicate questions on this subject (that is, the question is NOT being answered due to my lack of understanding, not due to the lack of knowledge trying to be imparted).  To me, my example looks like many other "answers" to those questions, yet... here we are.  I'm trying to learn this, so please type slowly.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class TestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) { makeTable(ThisType.CUSTOMER); }

private enum ThisType { CUSTOMER, TRANSACTION }

static <K, V> ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> makeTable(ThisType type) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> thisTable = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    Integer key = 0;
    String value = null;

    switch (type) {
    case CUSTOMER:
        key = 0;
        value = "nothing to report";
        break;
    case TRANSACTION:
        break;
    default:            
        break;

    }

    while (key < 10) {
        thisTable.put(key, value);
        key++;
    }

    return thisTable;
}

}
```

EDITED to replace "int" with "Integer".

Comment: The things you put into the map need to be of type `K` and `V`. You're putting in an `int` and a `String`, which the compiler cannot guarantee is compatible with the signature `<K, V>`. Also bear in mind that generic types must be objects - you need to use `Integer` instead of `int` for type arguments.

Comment: Note that the way you defined your method the compiler will try to infer the types of `K` and `V` from the assignment of the method's return value. The problem is that during compilation the compiler can't consider all calls to that method (there might be multiple with different types) and thus won't know what `K` and `V` actually are. In that case it's up to you to provide a means to create values of both types, e.g. by passing them as a parameter, passing classes and constructing instances from them, passing factories etc.

Comment: Think of it in another way: you're telling the compiler to create a dictionary for 2 languages (`K` and `V`) and upon calling could define that those two languages are English and French. However, inside the method all you put into the dictionary/map are Chinese and Spanish words. It _might_ happen that a caller wants exactly those 2 but chances are they won't and thus the compiler will refuse to build that dictionary in order not to get fired for producing the wrong one :)

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that the generic types of a method should enforce some constraint on the parameters and return type. For example, both parameters are defined by V, one parameter and the return type are defined by K. Otherwise generic methods are pretty useless.

Comment: @JonK incorrect: You can put in an `int`; autoboxing has been around for about a decade.

Comment: @JonK I updated the code snippet to have Integer; compiler still complains.  However, you highlight the struggle...

K and V are generic, or <K,V>; 
Integer and String are not, or <Integer, String>

Isn't that the very thing Generics are supposed to allow us to do?

Comment: @Bohemian Correct, but that's not what I said. I said that you can't use `int` as a type argument: `Map<String, int>` does not compile.

Comment: The Java Trail Maps are a good place to learn, but I strongly recommend http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/generics-tutorial-159168.pdf .  It superbly clarifies many generics issues.

Comment: @EricO When you create your map you're saying that its type arguments are `K` and `V`, either of which could be any class that ever has been or ever will be written. *Then* you're telling the compiler to pop an `Integer` object in as the key and a `String` object in as the associated value. If I invoke your method thus: `TestMain.<String, List<Long>>(ThisType.CUSTOMER)` then neither `K` or `V` are compatible with the values you're trying to put into them. The compiler knows that this is a possibility and so refuses to compile that code.

Comment: The way that your code is written it doesn't need you to be using generics in the way that you are. You're only ever putting strings in keyed by integers, so just make it a `ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>` instead (which is still using generics).

Comment: @JonK I decided to explore generics because I would like to be able to use one method to return ConcurrentHashMap of various types: <Integer, String>, <String, boolean[]>, <Integer, MyClass>, etc.   The data I want to load into them is read from various files, so the procedure to open and read is essentially the same for them.

Comment: @VGR in my OP, I link to the online version of that pdf.  I read it.  It did not help, but it did indeed make me feel far more sure that the code example I tried should be working.

Comment: @EricO: "I decided to explore generics because I would like to be able to use one method to return ConcurrentHashMap of various types" That's not what generics means. A generic method means that the *caller* can arbitrarily decide on what K and V are, and, without telling your method what it chose, it can expect your method to magically work with those types being what it chose. Your method doesn't get to decide what those types are -- rather, your method must work correctly no matter what I choose those method to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a ConcurrentHashMap to take a key of type K and a value of type V, but you attempt to add a key of type 'int' and a value of type String.

Comment: You've told me what I've done in my code, but have done nothing to explain how not-generic type's can't be represented through a generic type.  Isn't the entire purpose of generics to be able to represent <Integer/int, String> with <K,V> so that I might later decide to use <String, MyClass> somewhere else in the method?

Comment: @EricO <K, V> can represent any two types.  However, because you defined a Map with the type <K, V>, it can only accept a key of K and a value of V in your method.  It's not possible to define a data type with a generic and add a different type to it in the same method where it is defined.

Comment: So the question that needs to really be asked, is: How do I make Integer and String generic so that ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> can be returned as ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>?

Comment: Something like that is not possible.  Once an object has a type, it is not able to be changed unless it is successfully mapped to a new object.  I recommend you look at some existing questions that have been answered regarding generics as they will give you a better understand of what they are used for.

Comment: I have.  I even read the tutorial, as noted in the OP, that Oracle provides on the subject.  My code snippet, to me, looks very much like many of those answers I'm being referred back to; I even stated that despite reading many, many posts, I'm having trouble understanding -- and that's after ditching the posts that are trying to fix far larger conceptual problems than this simple one.